# Web API controller named Aux

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

This might sound silly but I tried to create a controller (WEB API - MVC 4)

```
public class AuxController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public User GetUser()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I called the API via jQuery

```
var options =
        {
            url: 'api/aux/getuser',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json'
        };
```

I get an error.

If I refactor the controller to

```
public class AudController : ApiController
```

and use the url option: 'api/aud/getuser'

it works nicely.

And you guessed it, if I refactor this back, it doesn't work.

Is there a good reason why this happens? Was it just my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain keywords such as AUX are not allowed in the URL. I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628004) will answer your question.

Comment: "And that is why, in 2009, when developing in Microsoft .NET 3.5 for ASP.NET MVC 1.0 on a Windows 7 system, you cannot include /com\d(\..*)?, /lpt\d(\..*)?, /con(\..*)?, /aux(\..*)?, /prn(\..*)?, or /nul(\..*)? in any of your routes." [link](http://bitquabit.com/post/zombie-operating-systems-and-aspnet-mvc/) - Thanks!