# Simple REST GET Webservice method 404 when passing parameter of "con"

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, exception, asp.net-web-api

I am having a weird problem -- I have a web api v2 REST webservice set up and it has been working very well.  It is a simple GET with one parameter provided.

I was doing some testing this morning though, and found when I put "con" as the parameter, i get a 404 service not found. I tried debugging, and the service is not hit at all!

If I put "conn" or any other combo i've tried, it works just fine. Really not sure why "con" would make it so the webservice is not hit at all -- the URL is not changing!

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

here is the webservice:

```
[Route("api/xxxx/getnameinsuredlike/{nameInsuredToMatch}/")]
    [HttpGet()]
    public string[] GetNameInsuredLike(string nameInsuredToMatch)
    {
        try
        {
            return xxxxService.GetLikeNameInsured(nameInsuredToMatch);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new[] {
                "Failure",e.ToString()
            };
        }
    }
```

The webservice gives a 404 and is not hit at all.

Example of URI

machinename/api/xxxx/getnameinsuredlike/con

If I have a different parameter (virtually any other) it works as expected, and can verify the webserivce is hit in debug mode

ex: 
machinename/api/xxxx/getnameinsuredlike/conn

machinename/api/xxxx/getnameinsuredlike/test

machinename/api/xxxx/getnameinsuredlike/a

Comment: Answer is given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625764/asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-fails-to-map-path-containing-the-string-con

Comment: Absolutely right, this is the exact same. I will delete the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

CON ia a keyword and some keywords are not allowed in the URL.

CON means Connection