# Web API - Reserved Word?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

**Have a very simple web API:

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

I can make calls to this web api calling via my data service controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers(string id)
{
    var cl = _SecurityRepository.GetUsers(id);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, cl);
}
```

Logic is very simple: Searches the DB for any last names that start with the last three letter in id

The call:

> http://example.com/api/dataservice/Getusers/lop

The Results:

```
[
  {
    "userID": "DLopez",
    "firstName": "Don",
    "lastName": "Lopez",
    "department": "Information Technology"
  },
  {
    "userID": "SLOPER",
    "firstName": "Steve",
    "lastName": "Loper",
    "department": "First Services"
  },
  {
    "userID": "DLOPES",
    "firstName": "Davey",
    "lastName": "Lopes",
    "department": "Public Info"
  }
]
```

It all works great.  Yeah!   However, in one circumstance I get a resource cannot be found error with this call:

> http://example.com/api/dataservice/Getusers/con

I can use id=can, cone, com, etc,... There are no problems with any of those api calls.  They all work great.  As soon as I search on con -> resource cannot be found!  Does anyone have a clue?  I'm lost.

Comment: Does it find any users? Can we see the code for the GetUsers(...) method? Is there any error handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, "con" is a reserved word and not allowed. The workaround is to include the following under `<system.web>` in your Web.config.

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625764/asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-fails-to-map-path-containing-the-string-con).